# How to prevent HTTP requests from caching

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

back-end personnel have been added no cache to the response headers,but response Status still displayed as (disk from cache) and response is not changed,if you manually refresh the browser will return to normal。

Comment: +your question i unclear, please use a little more words to describe your problem...

Comment: @McKabue When the page begins loading, to request interface then jump to the next page, and then click the browser back button to the previous page, the data is already changed, but from the browser network and see the data has not changed, and Status Code is 200(disk from cache)